# Why aren't modifications made to a python module's variables propagating to new parallel processes?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dask, python-module, dask-distributed

I have an embarrassingly parallel list of tasks I want to perform. Currently I'm importing the configuration for these tasks as a module.

example one-line configuration.py:

```
result_folder = "aFolder"
```

Up until now I have been calling my function in series instead of in parallel

```
def embarassing(x, conf):
    print(x)
    print(conf.result_folder)
    # ... do complicated things and return a value

if __name__ == "main":
    import configuration as conf
    x = 1
    y = embarassing(x, conf)
```

Now I've updated the code to take advantage of running these tasks in parallel.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
# ...
if __name__ == "main":
    import configuration as conf
    client = Client(n_workers=1)
    x = 1
    future = client.submit(embarassing, x, conf)
    y = future.result()
```

This all works fine. The problem is sometimes I want to run an ad-hoc set of cases, and until now I could always add

```
import configuration as conf
x = 2
conf.result_folder = "newFold"
```

and the code would print

```
2
newFold
```

but under the parallel code, it prints

```
2
aFolder
```

Why can't I pass this module as an argument any more?

Comment: You have created separate processes.  Changes made in one process are not seen by any other process.  Typically, you shouldn't start the second process until you've already set `conf.result_folder`.  There are ways of communication between processes, but they require a little bit of effort.

Comment: I am setting ```conf.result_folder``` before creating any more processes. ```x``` and ```conf.result_folder``` are set right after the line where ```conf``` is imported. That's why the change in ```x``` is being realized.

Comment: Where are you adding the code? stuff inside of a `__name__=="__main__"` section doesn't get executed in extra process.

Answer (score 0):

distributed uses pickle to send values to the worker. For modules, this is essentially just the name of the module, so that the worker does an import rather than saving the current state of the module, sending that and then recreating it in the worker.

If you want to send information to the worker tasks this way, you will need to send an ordinary variable (class instance, etc) rather than a module object. Alternatively, you could make a closure, or run the `conf.result_folder = "newFold"` line on the worker, or ... probably lots of options.